# Populating value in Kendo Mvc Grid based on a value from Kendo DropDown which is also in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC Grid row which have two columns. First cell is Id(dropdown) and second cell is Name.
First cell is a dropdown, so on the basis of value from dropdown i want to show the Name in the second cell.

I,m verymuch new to Kendo.

Comment: Please share what you try so far. I guess you are refering to the edit mode of the grid. Here is some documentation that can help. https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline - https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing - https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates

Comment: That use case doesn't make much sense if those are the only 2 fields. What are you trying to accomplish? Editing a list of value/descriptions perhaps?